# Qt, qmake, pro file: Add compiler name to target name

Tags: qt, qmake

I want to add the Qt version and compiler version to the target in .pro file like this:

```
msvc=$$basename(QMAKESPEC)
TARGET = Appname_Qt$${QT_VERSION}_$$msvc
message($$msvc)
message($$TARGET)
```

the result (message output) is:

```
Project MESSAGE: win32-msvc2008
Project MESSAGE: Appname_Qt4.7.1_win32-msvc2008
```

but the target output (file name) is:

```
Appname_Qt4.7.1_
```

the compiler name (version) was missed. How can I fix this?
Thank you so much!

//---- update ---------
I tried with:

```
msvc=$$basename(QMAKESPEC)
msvcx=abcd
TARGET = Appname_Qt$${QT_VERSION}_$$msvcx
message($$msvc)
message($$TARGET)
```

and the target output (file name) is:

```
Appname_Qt4.7.1_abcd
```

(correct)

Comment: Your original code works for me on Linux using Qt 5.4

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that: by the time `qmake` runs, the compiler and Qt version are already fixed: they are the ones used to build the `qmake` in question.

The compiler and Qt version are determined at the time Qt is built. You select what Qt version/compiler combo to use by running the correct `qmake` executable.

Suppose you had VS 2012 and VS 2015, and Qt 4.8 and 5.5 installed, in following combinations:

1. VS2012 + Qt 4.8
2. VS2012 + Qt 5.5
3. VS2015 + Qt 5.5

You'd have a `qmake.exe` in each of the builds. Each of them will generate a makefile that uses the proper compiler and Qt version. Additionally, you must start `qmake` in the environment where the given compiler is configured to be in the path: you have to run `vcvars` before running `qmake`. Qt Creator runs `vcvars` automatically for you each time before starting `qmake` or `nmake/jom`.

Comment: I know those. My purpose is to generate the target name for each Qt kit (including Qt version and compiler). I mean when I change the Qt kit. I don't need to update the pro file but the target name will change. As my example code, I can print out msvc but cannot append to the TARGET. This is my issue in the question.